# What is the dask equivalent of numpy.tile?

Tags: python, numpy, dask

Dask (http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html) is a flexible parallel computing library for analytics. It scales to big data, in constrast to Numpy and has many similar methods. How can I achieve the same effect as `numpy.tile` on a dask array?

Comment: Tile hasn't been implemented.  Raise an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`dask.array.concatenate()`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.concatenate) could be a possible workaround.

Demo in NumPy:

```
In [374]: x = numpy.arange(4).reshape((2, 2))

In [375]: x
Out[375]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])

In [376]: n = 3

In [377]: numpy.tile(x, n)
Out[377]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]])

In [378]: numpy.concatenate([x for i in range(n)], axis=1)
Out[378]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]])
```